# Can I use another websites drag and drop program to create an image that I will sell?

Tags: copyright, internet

More specifically can my customers do it? They want to create a design but have no programs or knowledge to create a design. So can I refer them to a website that has a simple drag and drop, add text and scale options to create their design, then send a screenshot of it to me so I can create the end product for them?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes - in the same way you can use paint that you didn't make to make a portrait you will sell or, more relevantly, a word processing program you didn't write to create a novel.